# Represent transformation respect to the following basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose I have the following transformation matrix
$$A = \pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}}$$

How would you represent it respect to this basis:

$$B = \left\{ \pmatrix{2 \cr 4}, \pmatrix{1 \cr 3} \right\}$$

? And why?

Answer (score 0):

$$A \pmatrix{2 \cr 4}=\pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}}\pmatrix{2 \cr 4}=\pmatrix{4\\1}=\frac{11}{2}\pmatrix{2 \cr 4}-7\pmatrix{1 \cr 3}$$

$$A \pmatrix{1 \cr 3}=\pmatrix{0 & 1 \cr \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{1}{2}}\pmatrix{1 \cr 3}=\pmatrix{3\\1}=4\pmatrix{2 \cr 4}-5\pmatrix{1 \cr 3}$$

So

$$A_{B,B}=\pmatrix{\frac{11}{2}&4\\-7& -5}$$